# How to make a regex to get a value within a certain row range?

Tags: java, regex

How to make a regex to select entire lines until it reaches a specific value in the limit of 5 lines down? If the value is more than 6 lines down then I should not select.

The configuration I'm doing is:

```
Multiline
Singleline
Global
```

This regex works until it reaches the final value, but I didn't want to select myvalue if it was too far from start, as the limit is 5.

```
start.*?(myvalue here)
```

The data I'm using:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
start
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4 
line 5
line 6 myvalue here
```

In the above case, the expected is not to select, if I had it on line 5 then I could select.

Could you show me how to do it in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for making sure only 0 t0 5 line breaks are there between start and end patterns:

```bash
^start(?:.*\R){0,5}.*?myvalue here
```

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/QRNHBI/1)

This will show no match because `myvalue here` appears after 6 lines.

If that end pattern appears after 5 lines then there will be a match as you can see in [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/QRNHBI/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^start`: Match `start` at a line start
- `(?:.*\R){0,5}`: Match 0 or more of any characters followed by a line break. Repeat this non-capturing group 0 to 5 times
- `.*?myvalue here`: Match `myvalue here` after matching 0 or more character on a line